# Does removing fields also removes submitted values?

Tags: webforms

I just removed each fields of a form in order to update them. Sadly, I'm afraid it also removes all the associated values submitted, because when I navigate to the 'Result' tab, values are missing.

Is there any way to recover this?
How could I fetch the whole submissions despite the fact that some fields does not exists anymore?

EDIT: I've root access to the MySQL database (currently searching inside it)

Some unsuccessful attempts:

```
-- Enable to fetch submitted data associated to a submission identified by its node id

SELECT * FROM webform_submissions
JOIN webform_submissions.nid = webform_submitted_data.nid
WHERE webform_submissions.nid = 42;

> Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

```
-- Verify that node id actually exists: it does

SELECT * FROM webform_submissions WHERE nid = 42 LIMIT 1;

> +------+--------+-------+----------+------------+---------------+
> | sid  | nid    | uid   | is_draft | submitted  | remote_addr   |
> +------+--------+-------+----------+------------+---------------+
> | 2538 | 42     | 26261 |        0 | 1613557280 | IP.ADD.RE.SS  |
> +------+--------+-------+----------+------------+---------------+
```

```
-- Verify that some submitted data related to this node id are present

SELECT * FROM webform_submitted_data
WHERE nid = 42;

> Empty set (0.00 sec)
-- Has it been deleted ?
```

Assumption: it has been deleted and I'm in a bad trouble !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As webform elements are deleted, all related submission data is deleted.